# How to increment a simple counter and perform and update_all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to take the current ActiveRecord, based on user login, and increment a counter by 1, and then update the database with the new incremented value, where the email address equals the logged in user.

Everything works in the code, except setting the new incremented value. I tried to set it to another variable first (`my_counter`) and then update, but assignment is where the failure lies.

```
if User.find_by_email(@email)
      User.increment_counter(:redirect_count, 1)
      @my_counter.to_int = :redirect_count
      User.update_all({:redirect_count => @my_counter}, :email => @email)
```

If I set `my_counter` to 9, then `Updateall()` it updates the database correctly.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`increment!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment!)

```
user = User.find_by_email(@email)
user.increment!(:redirect_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
user = User.find_by_email(@email)
user.redirect_count += 1
user.save
```

Comment: Yep I tried that and it choked, but...I can't guarantee that this was the exact syntax so let me try it again!

Comment: I'll go ahead and point out - if user.redirect_count is nil, it will need to be initialized to 0 before it can be incremented.  Incrementing nil would produce an error.

Comment: THANK YOU!  THANK YOU!  THANK YOU!  Worked like a charm!  So appreciated!  Have a great day!